# How to convert 3 SAT Problem to a Graph using some kind of reduction ~?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to convert 3 SAT Problem to a Graph using some kind of reduction ~?

Here is my example and I would like to transform it to a graph

$( V_4 \lor V_2 \lor  \lnot V_3) $ $\land (\lnot V_2 \lor  V_1 \lor V4) \land (\lnot V_2 \lor V_4 \lor \lnot V_1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Sean Weaver's [BDD Visualizer](http://www.cs.uc.edu/~weaversa/BDD_Visualizer.html) to turn your [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) of three clauses into a [Binary Decision Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram):

[image]

The input description:

```
; Text following a semicolon is ignored (comment)

order(v1, v2, v3, v4); 

and(or(v4,v2,not(v3)), 
    or(not(v2),v1,v4)), 
    or(not(v2),v4,not(v1))
   ); 

print($1);
```

---

> The expression can be minimized and mapped to a circuit of logical gates using [Logic Friday 1](http://sontrak.com/):

Entered:

```
F = (V4 | V2 | V3') & (V2' | V1 | V4) & (V2' | V4 | V1');
```

Minimized:

```
F = V4  + V2' V3' ;
```

The resulting circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: that is more than clear,thank you